# How to get nested form group controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created the reactive form like below

```
this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      "name": ["", Validators.required],
      "email": "",
      "info": this.fb.group({
        "name": ["", Validators.required],
      })
    })
```

I have added getter function for getting form controls like below

```
get f() { return this.customerForm.controls }
```

I am displaying the error messages like below

```
<p *ngIf="f.name.errors?.required">Required</p>
```

But I couldn't display the **info** error messages. Because it is in nesting group so that I have decided that create another getter for getting info form controls like below

```
  get fi() { return this.customerForm.controls.info.controls }
```

But it's not working also I couldn't find why it is not working. Could anyone help to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: controls is an array not an object. do this `this.customerFrom.get('info').controls`

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes. I am getting controls undefined

Comment: @ibenjelloun. Not working.

Comment: are you using chrome 80?

Comment: if you need to get info group controls you can get it as this.customerForm.get('info').controls

Comment: It is not working

Comment: @Chellappanவ I am working in firefox

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6eqzkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Your stack blitz is working

Comment: @Chellappanவ Thanks for you reply. Did you notice that controls have red border. The error is "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.ts(2339)
". I faced this issue now.

Comment: You can get rid that error by casting  get t() { return (this.f.info as FormGroup).controls; }

Answer (score 1):

on formGroup objects .errors property does not hold anything and would always return null. At group level You will only be able to tell if it is valid or invalid. for actual errors you will need to reach into the nested control.

```
this.customerForm.get('info').valid  // would work 
this.customerForm.get('info').invalid  // would work
this.customerForm.get('info').errors // will return null even if the control are in error
this.customerForm.get('info.name').errors // would work
```